# Remove or Re-style Lightning Components Loading Message

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

Is there a way to remove or re-style the Lightning Components Loading Message.

[image: Lightning Components Loading Message]

It doesn't fit visually into my app and I'd like to handle the loading message myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template feature from Aura OSS has recently been enabled for Lightning Components, and as of yet the docs, samples, etc. are sparse. A few things to get you started:

1. Create a new Lightning Component that serve as the template, extending aura:template and setting the isTemplate attribute to true:

   <aura:component isTemplate="true" access="GLOBAL" extends="aura:template">
   </aura:component>
2. Use the template for standalone Lightning Apps:

   <aura:application access="GLOBAL" template="c:blankTemplate">
       <sdsx:sdsTester />
   </aura:application>
3. Set the desired attributes and styles. Hint: set the display attribute on .auraMsgBox to something other than none so that it's displayed.The titlebar and loadingText attributes can be set to further establish app identity.

Here's an example that overrides some of the styles and attributes:

```
<aura:component isTemplate="true" access="GLOBAL" extends="aura:template">
<aura:set attribute="title" value="Lightning Demo"/>
<aura:set attribute="loadingText" value="Wait for it..."/>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: black;
    }

    .auraMsgBox {
        background-color: #000060;
        min-width: 160px;
        min-height: 160px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    .auraMsgBox .logo {
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .auraMsgBox h2 {
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```